# File handling - Check for a Whole Word

Tags: c, file, file-io

How to check for a string in a file as a whole word?

For example, when I use strstr() and search for a word "google", it includes both `google` and `agoogle`. I want to read word by word from a text file in C.

I use fgets, which reads a whole line from a text file.

**I have to find  the occurance of word google, not agoogle**

this is the code
i have the word ***google*** in argv[3]

```
            FILE *ptr;
            ptr=fopen(argv[4],"r+");
            if(ptr!=NULL)
                {
                        while(fgets(temp,521,ptr)!=NULL)
                        {

                            strlwr(temp);
                            if(strstr(temp,argv[3])!=NULL)
                                 {
                                    //printf("\nOne %s",temp);
                                    line_count++;
                                 }

                         }

            printf("L:%d",line_count);
     }//end of inner else
 }//end of else
getch();
```

Comment: search " google " instead of "google" with strstr. But doesn't work if word appears at the beginning of line!

Comment: So `agoogle` is not a match for the exact *word* `google`. Is the word inside a string `google,` a match? Is it in `Google`? How about `(google)`? The first half of `google.com` and the last half of `test_google`? Are accented characters significant -- `ágoogle` (and if so, in what encoding)?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch a line from a file using

```
fgets();
```

Then use `strtok()` to break your line into words with space as delimiter.(Delimiter may be anything as we are not able to see your input file,set delimiter accordingly)

Each token returned by `strtok()` you can use to check it against your string.
The same steps should be repeated until EOF.

You understanding on `strstr()` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/?kw=fscanf) with the specifier character `"%s"`.

`fscanf()` allow to you to read words. the words delimitors are the whitespaces.

Whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters:

```
' '     (0x20)  space (SPC)
'\t'    (0x09)  horizontal tab (TAB)
'\n'    (0x0a)  newline (LF)
'\v'    (0x0b)  vertical tab (VT)
'\f'    (0x0c)  feed (FF)
'\r'    (0x0d)  carriage return (CR)
```

Comment: even if i use fscanf,it also includes word  agoogle, as it matches with the pattern google"

Comment: @BHUPATHYAP to match the scanned word with your word use `strcmp()` and not `strstr()`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) of `strstr()`.

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

It says,

> return a pointer to the beginning of the substring, or NULL if the substring is not found.

So, obviously, it won't return both `google` and `agoogle` when searching for `google`. What exactly is your problem?

Next, `word by word from a text file in C`, either

1. use `fgets()` to read a complete line, and use space  as a delimiter to take out each *word*. use `strok()` [or `strtok_r()`, if provided by the extension]
2. use `fscanf()`

Comment: i have to read word by word from a text file in C, and must compare it with my string .and display whole words that match my string